# i want the below javascript program to give the output in array format, how can i do that?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**I wrote this javascript program to find sum of array elements, also i got the answer, but i want the answer to be in array format , how i can do that ?**

```
let arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
let sum=0;

for(let i=0; i<=arr.length-1; i++){
    sum=sum+arr[i];
    console.log(sum);
  }
```

here is the output i am getting

```
**output ==>** 
1 
3
6
10
15
```

this is the output i want

```
**expected output ==>**   [1,3,6,10,15]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    let arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
let sum=0;
var newarr = []
for(let i=0; i<=arr.length-1; i++){
    sum=sum+arr[i];
newarr.push(sum)
    
  }
console.log(newarr);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use javascript array.map function()**

```js
let arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
let sum=0;

var roots = arr.map(function(num) {
    sum=sum+num;
    return sum;
});
console.log(roots);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work.

Comment: To see the output just `console.log(roots)`

Comment: Why mix `let` and `var`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let sum = [arr[0]];

for (let i = 1; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {
  sum.push(sum[i - 1] + arr[i]);
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
let arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
let sum=0;
let arrayOfSum=[];
for(let i=0; i<=arr.length-1; i++){
    sum=sum+arr[i];
    arrayOfSum.push(sum);
}
console.log(arrayOfSum);
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to either store the running values of `sum` into `arr` (or into another array), then using `console.log`, which will format an array for you automatically.

Below is an implementation.

```
let arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
let sum=0;

for(let i=0; i<=arr.length-1; i++){
    sum=sum+arr[i];
    arr[i] = sum;
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 let arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
    function sum(nums) {    
    for(let i=1; i< nums.length; i++){
        nums[i] = nums[i] + nums[i-1];
      }
      return nums;
    }
    
    console.log(sum(arr));
```

No need to create new array just update the existing one with new values.